# Rails & ActiveAdmin - flash.now on custom pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Has anyone had success implementing `flash.now[:notice]` alerts within a custom page in ActiveAdmin?

I am using a custom page created with `ActiveAdmin.register_page "CustomPage"`.

`flash[:notice]` works, but I cannot use it because I am not using `redirect_to` so the alerts show on the incorrect page.

My Gemfile contains `gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'`

app/admin/test.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Test" do 
  content do 
    flash.now[:notice] = 'Test'
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post more of the custom page for reference?

Comment: custom page added. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `flash.now[:notice]` inside the `content` block is too late for it to be evaluated and rendered as part of the custom page. Instead you can set the flash message in a `before_action` in the controller:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Test" do
  content do
    # Test content
  end

  controller do
    before_action :set_notice, only: :index

    private

    def set_notice
      flash.now[:notice] = 'Test'
    end
  end
end
```

See the [filters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) section of the Action Controller Overview guide for more detail on `before_action`.